# Are there any benefits to running Cloudinary add-on vs. existing RoR with carrierwave integration

Tags: heroku, carrierwave, cloudinary

I have a functioning RoR app working with Cloudinary and carrierwave running on Heroku but I built it either before it was offered as an add-on or before I understood what an add-on was in Heroku.

Everything has been running smoothly but recently it seems image uploading may not be as fast as it could be and my app is stalling on 3Mb image which is well under the 10Mb limit.

Adding Cloudinary as an Add-on creates a completely new account and I already have client images in my existing Cloudinary account.

I noticed a timeout variable while searching around but have not tried changing my uploader configuration.

Any advice would be much appreciated. If advising me to create an add-on can you also suggest a reliable way to move my user's content to a new cloudinary account from an existing app?

Thank you.

Comment: There should be no functionality difference when using Cloudinary directly or when you sign up via a third party like Heroku - in both cases your API calls and image requests go to Cloudinary's servers directly, not via Heroku's system. There should be no problem using an existing account in your Heroku code, for example. If you're seeing slow upload performance, the most likely reason is the internet connection between the  client and the API servers, and if you think there's a problem there, please contact us directly with the details: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Thank you! Since posting I noticed I'm not using the js image handlers as specified in the cloudinary documentation. I will be adding that and retesting today and will reach out if needed. Thank you again for your support. This helps me cross off a big what if.